# kafkaRDD next() slow

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

My spark consumption Kafka has data accumulation problems. After troubleshooting, I found that data consumption is very time-consuming once about 10 minutes. I located the specific code here.

```
   while (consumerRecords.hasNext()) {
       long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
       ConsumerRecord<String, Message> consumerRecord = consumerRecords.next();
       long next = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin ;
   ....
```

The type of consumerRecords object is KafkaRDD, and the next() method took about 40 seconds to return the data. This caused data accumulation.

This is my information from monitoring

**2020/10/19 18:03:44.000 7 records 40 min 0.4 s 40 min

2020/10/19 18:03:43.500 2 records 40 min 0.4 s 40 min

2020/10/19 18:03:43.000 7 records 39 min 40 s 40 min

2020/10/19 18:03:42.500 2 records 39 min 0.4 s 39 min

2020/10/19 18:03:42.000 8 records 39 min 0.4 s 39 min**

I don’t know how to continue to troubleshoot this problem, or what causes it to be so time-consuming?

Please give me some guidance and suggestions, thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you need individual records from the RDD?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don’t understand what'individual records' means. The business here is to get Kafka messages and perform calculations. There is no other business. The calculation itself is very fast, but every four or five minutes, there will be a next() method that is very big. delay

Comment: `consumerRecords.next()` will read one record at a time. If you simply need to consume and process Kafka events, you can use the standard Java consumer library, not Spark, which is more commonly used with structured streaming (the RDD API for Kafka is considered deprecated)

Comment: It's also not clear at what rate your producer is sending data into the topic, but the consumer poll is a blocking call, and can easily take several seconds to minutes depending on what parameters you've given it

Comment: Is'standard Java consumer' the same way as spring-kafka? Can it be used in spark? Is there an example of usage? Our company's selection is spark, which is difficult to replace.
The rate at which producers produce data is very fast.

Comment: Spring provides a wrapper around `kafka-clients` basic Java library. Example code can be found here - https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/6.0.0-post/clients/cloud/java/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/clients/cloud/ConsumerExample.java#L34

Comment: Or as mentioned, you might want to try [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Comment: Recently, I changed the kafkaRDD to this kind of trial, but I still want to figure out what is wrong with the data pull, why it is delayed for 40 seconds

Comment: Are there other Kafka consumers in the same group ID? Are the topics healthy with all replicas and leaders assigned? Is Zookeeper healthy? ... There are lots of considerations, and I would still be interested if you can isolate the problem to the machine you are running the code on, Spark itself, or just the basic consumer API